# Exchange PowerShell Script: "Assignment statements are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section"

Tags: c#, powershell

I trying to execute the powershell script in C#. But I am getting the exception like **"Assignment statements are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section."**

**Here is my C# code :**

```
 string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\script.ps1");

 PowerShell exec_script = PowerShell.Create();
 exec_script.RunspacePool = rs;
 exec_script.AddScript(script);

IAsyncResult exec_AsyncResult = exec_script.BeginInvoke();
PSDataCollection exec_Result = exec_script.EndInvoke(exec_AsyncResult);

foreach (PSObject cmdlet in exec_Result)
{   
          PSMemberInfoCollection collec = cmdlet.Members;                       
          foreach (PSMemberInfo temp in collec)
          { 
                    Console.WriteLine(temp.Name + "\t\t\t\t:\t" + temp.Value);
          }                       
}
```

**Here is my PowerShell script :**

```
[Collections.ArrayList]$serverList = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
[string]$server

if ($server -eq "")
{
                $objects = Get-MailboxServer
                foreach ($object in $objects)
                {
                                $out = $serverList.Add($object.Name)
                }
}

else
{
                $serverList.Add($server)
}
```

wondering what is the problem.

Thanks is advance,

**Viswanath B**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a server restriction on Exchange: check [this thread on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/46767d4b-e338-4bff-a38e-63b4d4903408).